# How to show mat-card on top of another mat-card using FlexLayout

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I have shown the mat-card using flexLayout as like below.
[image: Current Working code]

**Code Block of the structure in the above image**

```
<mat-card>
 <mat-card-content>
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly centre">
   <div fxFlex="40">
      {{UserName}}
   </div>
   <div fxFlex="60">
     <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly centre">
        <div fxFlex="60>
           <button>{{add_btn}}</button>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex="40">
          <button>{{delete_btn}}</button>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Now i would like to show the card which has two buttons 'Soft Delete' and 'Hard Delete' while hovering the 'Delete' Button. I have used Flexlayout for responsive UI. The issue which i am facing now is . I have write the hover code block inside fxFlex="40". Due to that the SoftDelete and HardDelete buttons are showing as wrapped. so please help me to achieve this UI.

```
<mat-card>
 <mat-card-content>
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly centre">
   <div fxFlex="40">
      {{UserName}}
   </div>
   <div fxFlex="60">
     <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly centre">
        <div fxFlex="60>
           <button>{{add_btn}}</button>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex="40">
          <button (mouseover)="showcards()">{{delete}}</button>
          <mat-card-content *ngIf="isTrue">
                  <div fxLayout="column">
                     <div fxFlex="50">
                          <button>{{softdelete_btn}}</button> 
                     </div>
                     <div fxFlex="50">
                          <button>{{harddelete_btn}}</button> 
                     </div>                  
                  </div>
          </mat-card-content>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `(click)` event rather than `(mouseover)`. It will better suit for your layout as whenever you click the Soft Delete button and hide the smaller card, the mouse will stay hovered on the main Delete button and it will re-trigger the mouseover event.

```html
<style>
    .card {
        box-shadow: 0 10px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>

<mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center">
            <div fxFlex="40">
                Username
            </div>
            <div fxFlex="60">
                <div fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center">
                    <div fxFlex="60">
                        <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Add</button>
                    </div>
                    <div fxFlex="40">
                        <button *ngIf="!isTrue" (click)="showcards()" mat-raised-button color="primary">Delete</button>
                        <div *ngIf="isTrue" class="card" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="50px" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
                            <div fxFlex="50">
                                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="showcards()">Soft Delete</button>
                            </div>
                            <div fxFlex="50">
                                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="showcards()">Hard Delete</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxgccq) for the same.